# HttpClient call to web api method with integer parameter Returns error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I really can't see what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to call a asp.net core web api method that accepts an integer via `HttpClient` but it returns a `404` error.

**`HospitalController` (Web API)**

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("GetById")]
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
    return Json(_hospitalService.Get(id));
}
```

**`HospitalController` (MVC)**

```
protected string url = "http://localhost:5001/api/Hospital";

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    if (id.Equals(0))
        return StatusCode(404);

    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url + "/GetById/" + id); //returns 404 error here.
    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var hospital = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hospital>(responseData);
        var hospitalVM = Mapper.Map<HospitalViewModel>(hospital);
        return View(hospitalVM);
    }

    return View("Error");
}
```

I have a POST method in the same controller in MVC that works. But this GET method returns a 404 and I can't seem to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two route templates being used in the api according to

```
[HttpGet("{id}")] //Matches GET api/Hospital/5
[Route("GetById")] //Matches GET api/Hospital/GetById
```

neither of which match what is being called

```
http://localhost:5001/api/Hospital/GetById/5
```

`Http{Verb}` attribute is usually used on RestFul APIs.

> When building a REST API, it's rare that you will want to use `[Route(...)]` on an action method. It's better to use the more specific `Http*Verb*Attributes` to be precise about what your API supports. Clients of REST APIs are expected to know what paths and HTTP verbs map to specific logical operations.

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

update the route template on the web api to map to the desired route

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HospitalController : Controller {

    //...code removed for brevity

    //Matches GET api/Hospital/GetById/5
    [HttpGet("GetById/{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {
        return Ok(_hospitalService.Get(id));
    }
}
```

Also HttpClient is meant to be used asynchronously, so the MVC controller would also need to be refactored as mixing blocking calls `.Result` can cause deadlocks

```
protected string url = "http://localhost:5001/api/Hospital";

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id) {
    if (id.Equals(0))
        return StatusCode(404);

    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url + "/GetById/" + id);
    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var responseData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var hospital = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hospital>(responseData);
        var hospitalVM = Mapper.Map<HospitalViewModel>(hospital);
        return View(hospitalVM);
    }

    return View("Error");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the deep insight. It worked pretty nicely. But quick question, assuming I have an api method accepting multiple parameters like an int and string, how do I write the HttpGet attribute for the method? I am going to mark your answer as correct but I need help with this second question. Thanks.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha, It depends on what you want the url to look like. The link included in my answer points to official documentation about how to do attribute routing, including route templates and rout constraints. You can have multiple parameters of different types.

Comment: Thank you very much